# regarding each method and the object(' ','[ ]')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, view, each

I cant understand the difference of these method.Please teach me.
In products#show(view),if I use each method on the line 6(<% [@product].each do |item| %>), then this program will run.but if I use each method on the line 6(<% @product.each do |item| %>), then this program cant run.
What is the difference of these program?

Products#show(view)

```
<div class="contents">
    <h1>Products#show</h1>
    <p>Find me in app/views/products/show.html.erb</p>

    <ul>
        <% [@product].each do |item| %>
            <!--画像を追加したい-->
            <li>Item name:<%= item.name %></li>
            <li>Kind of item:<%= item.kind %></li>
            <li>Size of item:<%= item.size %></li>
            <li>Explanation:<%= item.discription %></li>
            <li>Price:<%= item.price %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Edit this item",edit_user_product_path,class:"btn btn-default btn-danger" %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Destroy this item",method: :delete,confirm:"Are u sure?",class:"btn btn-default btn-danger" %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>

    <li><%= link_to "User's page",user_path,class:"btn btn-default" %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Product Timeline",user_products_path(:user_id => @user.id),class:"btn btn-default" %></li>

</div>
```

ProductsController

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  include ProductsHelper

  before_action :signed_in_user,only:[:new,:create]
  before_action :find_user_object,except:[:show]
  before_action :products_objects_for_index, except:[:show]


  def index
    #before actionで@userあり
    products_object_create_for_index #@all_products
    sign_in @user
    flash[:notice] = "You have to signin!!" if signed_in?
    #render :template => "products/index"  
  end

  def show
    #@product = Product.new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @product = @user.products.build #これが1つのオブジェクト
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.find_by(user_id:@product.user_id)

  end


  def new
    # => 多分before action化させる方が良い
    #urlでproducts/newなっててUserのidが取れてない。
    redirect_to signin_url, notice:"U have to sign in to publish your furniture." unless sign_in @user
    @product = Product.new
  end

  def create
    @product = @user.products.build(products_params)
    if @product.save
      @product.update_attributes(:user_id => @user.user_id)
      flash[:success] = "You could add new item:)"
      redirect_to @user #後にaction: :indexに変更したい
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "You couldn't add an item."
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @product.update_attributes(products_params)
      flash[:success] =  "You updated your product info"
      redirect_to @products
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "couldn't update :("
      redirect_to products_edit_path
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy
    redirect_to user_path
  end




  private

  def products_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:id,:user_id,:name,:kind,:size,:discription,:price)
  end


  #before_action
  def signed_in_user
    redirect_to signin_url, notice:"Please sign in." unless signed_in? 
  end

  def find_user_object
    @user = User.find_by(params[:user_id])
  end

  def products_objects_for_index
      @product = Product.new
      @product = Product.find_by([:id]) if @product.id
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have conflicting variables in your show action

```
def show
  #@product = Product.new
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @product= @user.products.build 
  @product = Product.find(params[:id]) # this overrides your previous @product variable
  @user = User.find_by(user_id:@product.user_id) #this overrides your previous @user variable
end
```

*So if you look at the comments in code your **@product variable contains a single value and it's not an array of values and hence when you use @product.each you get a error but when you use [@product].each you basically makes it an array which contains @product and hence you don't get any error***

**Fix**

Looking at your code i think you want to show all the products that belongs to a user so in your show action you can do:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @products= @user.products 
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end    

#show.html.erb
<% @products.each do |item| %>
  // your code
<% end %>
```

Comment: OMG!! That's what I want to know! I really appriciate you:) Thank you.

Comment: @user3674902 i have updated my answer for a possible fix. If you want to display something else then let me know, will update my answer accordingly